# How to make my pygame game window resizeable?

Tags: python, pygame

When I run this code the resizeable option is available but when I click on it to maximize the screen, there is this weird white outline that appears. How would I fix it?[image].

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((900, 500), pygame.RESIZABLE)


running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to recreate the display [`Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) in the `VIDEORESIZE` event (see [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html)):

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((900, 500), pygame.RESIZABLE)

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
            screen = pygame.display.set_mode(event.size, pygame.RESIZABLE)
    pygame.display.update()
```